# Improve sql query that used scalar-value functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function, sqlperformance

I have a query that used 2 scalar-value functions. Both these functions are almost the same, just one return `MIN` value and another `MAX` value.

```
SELECT
    SSR.ScoreGroupId AS ScoreRuleGroup,
    [dbo].[fnCalculateMinScore](@ruleSetId, SSR.ScoreGroupId) AS MinScore,
    [dbo].[fnCalculateMaxScore](@ruleSetId, SSR.ScoreGroupId) AS MaxScore,
    SSR.ScoreStrengthId AS ScoreValue,
    SSR.LowerBound,
    SSR.UpperBound
FROM [dbo].[ScoreStrengthRange] SSR
WHERE SSR.ScoreRuleSetId = @ruleSetId
```

`MIN` function has next query:

```
DECLARE @minScore int

SELECT @minScore = SUM(MinScore)
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(SRV.Score) AS MinScore
    FROM ScoreRule SR
    INNER JOIN ScoreRuleValue SRV
        ON SR.Id = SRV.RuleId
    WHERE SR.[Status] <> 1
          AND SR.GroupId = @groupId
          AND SRV.ScoreRuleSetId = @ruleSetId
    GROUP BY SRV.RuleName
) T

RETURN ISNULL(@minScore, 0)
```

While `MAX` function almost the same, just use `MAX` instead of `MIN`

```
DECLARE @maxScore int

SELECT @maxScore = SUM(MaxScore)
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(SRV.Score) AS MaxScore
    FROM ScoreRule SR
    INNER JOIN ScoreRuleValue SRV
        ON SR.Id = SRV.RuleId
    WHERE SR.[Status] <> 1
          AND SR.GroupId = @groupId
          AND SRV.ScoreRuleSetId = @ruleSetId
    GROUP BY SRV.RuleName
) T

RETURN ISNULL(@maxScore , 0)
```

I thought of creating 1 function, that will return both MAX and MIN values. My thought is that it can improve performance a bit, but don't know how to implement it in such query as a new function will be not scalar but table-value function.

Does it make sense a bit (haven't checked execution plans as what I want isn't implemented)? Thanks.

Comment: It should be easy to completely drop the functions and include the subquery they essentially are in the query itself. That way the optimizer has access to it and may possibly improve performance.

Comment: I agree with @stickybit, why have 2 functions that are essentially aggregating values when you can perform the aggregation inline on the main query? That would be much simpler

Comment: Thanks, @stickybit and Tanner. Will try

Comment: @demo . . . To emphasize stickybit's point:  If you care about performance, don't use a UDF at all.